# TypesScript: unable to read a property of an object even though it's there

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, typescript, console.log

I'm trying to create a body and send my url to the backend where it stores my `content` objects. However when I use `const body = JSON.stringify(content);` It doesn't read the property `file`.

Here are is my service code:

```
addMessage(content: Content) {
    console.log("Service:", content); // File property is in the content object I sent
    const body = JSON.stringify(content); // File property missing here
    console.log("Body:", body);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
        : '';
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/content' + token, body, {headers: headers})
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const result = response.json();
            const newContent = new Content(
                result.obj.name,
                result.obj.user.firstName,
                result.obj._id,
                result.obj.user._id,
            );
            this.contents.push(newContent);
            return newContent;
        })
        .catch((error: Response) => {
            this.errorService.handleError(error.json());
            return Observable.throw(error.json());
        });
}
```

Here's my console:

[image]

You can see that file is in content but doesn't appear in body. I tried doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content));` and to my surprise, `content.file` was undefined. Any idea what could've went wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: See the little square box beside Content in the picture: hover it and read the pop up! https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCxf0.png!

Comment: That means that when unfolding the object's log, the console shows the value of that object at the moment of unfolding, not showing the value of the object as it was when the log happened! So if the object get changed after the log the unfolding will show the changes too! So the `file` property is probably added after some time from the log!

Comment: The string log is a different story! You transform the object into a string and log the string! The string remains the same so any changes on the object are not reflected in the console! It's like a picture of someone in his 20s shown 50 years later! The object in the picture (string) may have been changed (new properties added to it, removed...) but the log will still show the object as it was the moment the log has happened!

Comment: The other properties are not shown because they are ignored by `JSON.stringify` as their values are `undefined`s!

Comment: Is there a `toJSON` method on `content` object's prototype chain?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(content));` ?

First you need to `parse` the `JSON`, and once parsed you `stringify` it.

Let me know if it helps you! :D

Comment: `content` is already a JSON, so I can't call `JSON.parse()` on it. When I tried `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(content)` is didn't return file, only user, username, and tags. I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @YSA Try `JSON.stringify(content.json())`. I'm hitting desperation here. My girlfriend is going to kill me if I don't go to bed in the next 10 minutes... hehehe

Comment: @YSA Try also `let body = content.json();`. I will keep researching in the meanwhile.